# Inversion across an ellipse

Tags: algebraic-geometry, conic-sections

Let's take an ellipse with the standard equation

$$\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4}=1$$

And I am trying  to invert the following ellipse across that ellipse

$$\frac{4x^2}{3}+4\left(y-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2=1$$

I obtain a very strange curve with the equation:

$$\frac{4\left(\frac{36x}{9y^2+4x^2}\right)^2}{3}+4\left(\left(\frac{36y}{9y^2+4x^2}\right)-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2=1$$

Does anyone know what the general equation of the type of quartic curve formed is? It looks like an egg of some sort, but I would like to know the generalized equation of that egg so that I can change its parameters and apply a horizontal shrink, for example. Thanks!

Comment: What in general is meant by inverting ellipse 1 across ellipse 2? It looks like you somehow got the point $(u,v)$ frion the first ellipse, and then plugged in $(x,y)=(u,v)$ into the formula of the second ellipse. So I'm first wondering how you got the $u,v$ from the first ellipse, and secondly wondering why this substitution is called inverting the first ellipse across the second (i.e. what is the geometric meaning of the inversion).

Comment: @coffeemath To answer the first question, the (u,v) is defined as a mapping from (x,y) to $$\left(\frac{a^2b^2x}{a^2y^2+b^2x^2},\frac{a^2b^2y}{a^2y^2+b^2x^2}\right)$$ where $a$ and $b$ belong to the first ellipse of inversion. 2, inversion can be found here - http://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.6378v1.pdf. Hope this helps! Also, what I really care about atm is the curve found as a result of the process. What's it called? How to express it in general terms to apply transformations to it? For eg, for a horizontal shrink, tried expanding, and changing the x term but it didn't work! Maybe i expanded wrong?